# Qt + iOS - Where is AppDelegate?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, qt

I have been playing around with the QtQuick/QtCreator ios projects some. I was interested to see if I could make a Qt project that made use of the BackgroundFetch that is in ios7.

I couldn't figure out how to do it in my QtCreator project, so I loaded the generated Xcode project into Xcode to see if I could figure out how to do it there. I can still go to the project's Capabilities and add "Background Modes" to it, however, I couldnt find the AppDelegate type classes that I would normally use to set the Fetch interval, etc.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this for Qt ios projects?

Comment: I noticed this: https://github.com/richardmg/qtdd13_qmlapp which does some work wtih the camera using an ios camera delegate. Not sure if related.

Answer (score 1):

In your .pro:

```
ios {
  OBJECTIVE_SOURCES = ios/ios_app_delegate.mm
}
```

In ios/ios_app_delegate.mm:

```
#import "UIKit/UIKit.h"
#import "UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h"

@interface QIOSApplicationDelegate
@end

@interface QIOSApplicationDelegate (WoboqApplicationDelegate)
@end

@implementation QIOSApplicationDelegate (WoboqApplicationDelegate)

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSLog(@"launch!");
    UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:UNAuthorizationOptionBadge
      completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
          if(granted == YES) {
              [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
          };
      }];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
{
}
@end
```